# Erro HTTP Status 405 Servlet

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Estive fazendo o exercício "5.5 Primeira Servlet" da apostila sobre Java Web FJ21 da Caelum,fiz o código,reiniciei o Tomcat como foi pedido mas quando abro o link "http://localhost:8080/fj21-agenda/oi" para acessar a pagina ocorre o erro:

> **HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> **description** The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

CÓDIGOS:

```
public class OiMundo extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.service(request, response);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Primeira Servlet</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Oi mundo Servlet!</h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>fj21-agenda</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletOiMundo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.caelum.servlet.OiMundo</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletOiMundo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oi</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta retirar a chamada para a super classe:

```
super.service(request, response);
```

Quando você realiza o override do método service, tudo que você precisa tem de estar dentro do seu override, não é necessário repassar a chamada para o método padrão do `HttpServlet`.